# entityName.state must have a defined type

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new in doing coreData programming, i followed a tutorial and was doing step by step, while i got this error and got stucked up, Dont know what this means

```
  entityName.state must have a defined type

    entityName.zip must have defined type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set the datatype for the entity, meaning that CoreData does not what type the property is.
In your CoreData model make sure that the `Attribute Type` is set and recreate you CoreData files.

[image: CoreDara Attribute type]